# How do I fix a gap in my door?

Tags: doors, seal

There is a fairly large gap between the door and the frame. How do i fix this? [image]

Comment: Can you take a picture of the frame on the opposite side of the door?

Comment: first you need to figure out if the door is shrinking or the house is growing

Comment: Or possibly this door was just hung poorly.

Comment: With a deadbolt, I presume this is an exterior door?

Comment: Another picture from the same angle but with the same picture with the door open would be helpful. I'm wondering if the door's just missing it's weather stripping/ gasket.